# How To Add Billing to Shopify Node and Express App

Tags: node.js, express, shopify, in-app-billing, shopify-app

I have been building a Shopify app with Node / Express and I want to add billing to my app, but I am confused which portion of the Shopify documentation I should follow.

Would I follow the instructions under [Charge A Fee Using The Billing API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/tutorials/build-a-shopify-app-with-node-and-react/charge-a-fee-using-the-billing-api) because this is under Build a Shopify App with Node and React and their does not appear to be a dedicated article for Build a Shopify App with Node and Express.

OR

Would I follow the instructions under [Adding billing to your app](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/tutorials/adding-billing-to-your-app#step-1-create-a-recurring-charge) by adding a Ruby file into my app?

Is there an example of this in the Shopify Git Hub Repo? I may be missing it when looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build billing API from your side in `node express` with using shopify billing API

[shopify billing API](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/billing)

you can check there and select one billing method as your requirement

like if you want 30 days billing period than you can use recurring application charges api

[RecurringApplicationCharge](https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/billing/recurringapplicationcharge)

you can check all details how to use billing api in your project. It provides create new plan ,update plan and get plan details

method: you can call this API using `request-promise` from your `node.js` API and get response and use that response